# Acces Denied errno: 1045 on POST method. Mysql 8 Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, pool

I created a database in mysql, I have mysql 8 installed through homebrew.
So far so good, I connect to the database without problems, but when I try to upload data to the database through an INSERT I get the following error::

```
[nodemon] 2.0.19
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node src/`
Server on port: 4000
DB is Connected!
GET /expenses/add 200 35.845 ms - 1756
GET /css/style.css 304 11.540 ms - -
Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
    at Sequence._packetToError (/Users/manubrandes/Documents/proyects/El-Contador-1/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/Users/manubrandes/Documents/proyects/El-Contador-1/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:123:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/Users/manubrandes/Documents/proyects/El-Contador-1/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/Users/manubrandes/Documents/proyects/El-Contador-1/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/Users/manubrandes/Documents/proyects/El-Contador-1/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (/Users/manubrandes/Documents/proyects/El-Contador-1/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/manubrandes/Documents/proyects/El-Contador-1/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/manubrandes/Documents/proyects/El-Contador-1/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/manubrandes/Documents/proyects/El-Contador-1/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/Users/manubrandes/Documents/proyects/El-Contador-1/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (/Users/manubrandes/Documents/proyects/El-Contador-1/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (/Users/manubrandes/Documents/proyects/El-Contador-1/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
    at Pool.query (/Users/manubrandes/Documents/proyects/El-Contador-1/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:202:8)
    at node:internal/util:361:7
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Pool.query (node:internal/util:347:12)
    at /Users/manubrandes/Documents/proyects/El-Contador-1/src/routes/expenses.js:19:20
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/manubrandes/Documents/proyects/El-Contador-1/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) {
  code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
  errno: 1045,
  sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)",
  sqlState: '28000',
  fatal: true
}
POST /expenses/add 200 9.534 ms - 18
```

**If you look first the connection works but then I get this error.**

Here my code in database.js

```
const { Console } = require('console');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const { database } = require('./keys'); 
const pool = mysql.createPool(database);

pool.getConnection((err,connection) => {
    if (err) {
        if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {
            console.error('DATABASE CONNECTION WAS CLOSED');
        }
        if(err.code === 'ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR'){
            console.error('DATABASE HAS TO MANY CONNECTIONS')
        }
        if(err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED'){
            console.error('DATABASE CONNECTION WAS REFUSED')
        }
    }

    if (connection) connection.release();
    console.log('DB is Connected!');
    return;
})

pool.query = promisify(pool.query);

module.exports = pool;
```

My keys.js archive

```
module.exports = {
    database: {
        connectionLimit : 100,
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        user: 'root',
        pass:'mypass',
        database: 'db_moneymanager'
        }
}
```

And finally the file where I am making the post:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

//Conexion a la db
const pool = require('../database');

router.get('/add', (req, res) => {
    res.render('expenses/add');
});
 
router.post('/add', async(req, res) => {
    const { title, amount, description } = req.body;
    const newExpense = {
         title,
         amount,
         description
     };
    await pool.query('INSERT INTO outgoings set ?', [newExpense]);
    res.send('Received')
});

module.exports=router
```

**I already try this:**

```
CREATE USER 'manueldev'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pepe';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, PROCESS, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER ON *.* TO 'manueldev'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
ALTER USER 'manueldev'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'pepe';
```

Thank you very much for taking the time to read the problem and try to give me a solution.

Comment: _"If you look first the connection works"_. No, you're just ignoring the `ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR` error.

Comment: No i am not ignoring that. I mean when I start the application the connection to the database is successful. Then when i try to post with a form i get that error

Comment: You're checking for three specific errors, none of which is `ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a fresh install of MySql?

I believe you created a database user for your application access `manueldev`, however, your database config has the user `root`.

Try using the correct username and password, and give it a try.

Comment: I tried both and it didn't work. I install mysql with brew install mysql

Comment: Did you restart the mysql service after creating the user manueldev/pepe ?

Comment: Yes, I don't know what else to do

Comment: @ManuelBartolomeBrandes, as @robertklep mentioned, you are just checking the 3 type of errors in your `if(err) {...}` block hence you are under the impression that the connection to database is successful. You should have a default case too!

Comment: Also, I'd recommend to grant the permission using this statement `GRANT ALL ON db_moneymanager.* TO 'manueldev'@'localhost';`. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).